# Make Input Type=“Password” Use Number Pad on Mobile Devices with IE

Tags: php, jquery, html

I would like to change the password input to display a numerical keypad (the same as `type="number"` does).

```
<input type="password" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
```

but this does not work with IE. Is it possible to do this with another method?

Comment: So you want to limit the range of characters a user can have in their password, and so make it a lot less secure?

Comment: just numeric password!!! could be hacked quickly....

Comment: guys, lots of sites - including banking sites - use pin numbers, I don't think the OP is being unreasonable here

Comment: He doesn't say what this is for.  It could be any number of inputs that you would want masked.  Stop telling him it's a bad idea when you don't know anything about it.  For example, some sites password mask the security (last 3) numbers of my credit card in the exact way he's looking for.  Try asking questions, or answering him.

Comment: @roryok do you know any banking site which lets you in with only numeric password.

Comment: @Jai - Did he say "only numeric password"?  No.  Mine does this exact thing but also has another password field.

Comment: I'm not worry about security because I'm using this for low level identification

Comment: Guys I need show numeric pad as default but not letters pad. because for identification process I using something as employee no. So I would like show numeric pad first and save time

Comment: @jai, there could be non-numeric passwords before or after this. He never stated this was the *only* security method. My own bank does this. And in fact, my mobile provider had only a pin number until quite recently on their site, with a limited number of attempts before lock out.

Comment: Browser support for inputmode seems almost non-existent, and who uses IE on their mobile ?

Comment: @adeneo: Windows phone users. All 3 of us ... ;)

Comment: That was low, there are at least 10 of us

Comment: @adeneo Windows phone only has IE as their browser. No other browser exists, only different versions of IE. No chrome, no Firefox, no Opera... Just plain sucky IE on it.

Comment: Why don't you do like this: You shove an `<input type="number">` on top of a `<input type="password">`. Set the first one to be transparent (**NOT INVISIBLE!!!, JUST `opacity:0`**). After that, make a javascript tied on the `onkeydown` event, so that you ignore the change on that input and append it to the `<input type="password">` and handle things like pressing tab and backspace.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my previous answer, because as @IsmaelMiguel said, it wasn't helpful. Here's an implementation of what he suggested in the comments. If anyone feels like upvoting this please upvote his comment too.

Overlay a transparent `type=number` field on the password field.

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <input id="mask" type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" style="position:absolute;opacity:0;" />
    <input id="pin" type="password" />
</div>
```

jQuery is used to pass the value from the number field to the password field

```
$(function(){
    $("#mask").on("keyup", function (e) {
        $("#pin").val($("#mask").val());
    });
});
```

I've tested this and it works in IE11 on Windows 8.1. The only issue with it is the cursor is invisible, since the mask is always selected.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rz2tbbxk/1/)